# Objective C, NSData never gets data from web contents

Tags: objective-c

```
NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post.imageURL]];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
```

I have this code and imgData always gets nil. I checked post.imageURL and it returns a string which in a url format. I also replaced the string with a constant string(URL format) that I hardcoded but imgData still got null. This code runs on the background. Do you guys see any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good, are you sure your URL is valid ?
If post.imageURL is not valid, thus URLWithString: will be null and also your data.

I have tried with "http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png" to be sure, and it worked, so I guess the problem come from your URL.

Split your code :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png"];
NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
```

And check the value of each of the variable.